# copy file from one location to another location in linux using java program

Tags: java, file-io

Using JSP am trying to move customer logo into another location in linux but its not working.
thanks in advance

Here is my program

```
String customerLogo = request.getParameter("uploadCustomerLogo").trim();

StringBuffer absoluteFolderPath = new StringBuffer();

absoluteFolderPath.append("/zoniac");

absoluteFolderPath.append("/Companies/");

absoluteFolderPath.append("companyCode/");

absoluteFolderPath.append("custom/");

String destination = absoluteFolderPath.toString();

File sourcefile = new File(customerLogo);

File destfile = new File(destination+sourcefile.getName());

FileUtils.copyFile(sourcefile,destfile);
```

Comment: You should do that in a Servlet and not inside a jsp file

Comment: no exception  and also no image in the destination folder

Comment: is there any other way to copy or move image file in linux using jsp

Comment: @Enrique, why not inside a JSP file?  It compiles to a servlet anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to write java code in servlet.

and this method will work, you need to provide physical path to file , it seems you are providing relative path in web context.

Answer (score 1):

This level of logic code really should go into the servlet.  I think you need to take the stream of the file instead of just the file name.
http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/jsp/tutorial/multipart.xtp
http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/file_upload/index.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn how to run your JSP-code under a debugger.  The ones in Eclipse and Netbeans (at least) work very well if properly set up.

You will most likely find that the values of sourcefile and destfile are not what you expect.

Also, your unchecked use of the uploadCustomerLogo is an exploit waiting to be found.